Is there any method to access the variable from grandparent where parent and grand parent have same variable or method in java?
I have 3 classes in which first class is subclassed by second class and that second class is also subclassed by third class. Both the first and second class have same variable (both public). Now I want to access the value of the variable in first class from third class.
Let's say x = 2 in first class and x = 5 in second class. I am trying to access x = 5 from third class. I have used super.super.x , but it is showing error.
